# HasManyThrough limit query to specific date range

Tags: laravel

I am able to retrieve all commenters on a user's post with this

```
user.php
public function commentersOnUserPost() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Commenter', 'App\Post');
}

usersController
$commenters = $user->commentersOnUserPost;
```

But now i want to find out all commenters who commented on a user's post within a given date range. However i get this error

```
Method getBtnDates does not exist.
```

when i add

```
usersController
$commenters = $user->commentersOnUserPost->getBtnDates($startDate, $finishDate)->get();

commenter.php
public function scopeGetBtnDates($query, $from, $to){
    return $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $from)
        ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $to);
}
```

How can i go about this ?

Comment: You need to call the scope on the relationship, not the collection. Note the use of `()` after `commentersOnUserPost`. `$commenters = $user->commentersOnUserPost()->getBtnDates($startDate, $finishDate)->get();`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. @fubar. when i add the () i get this error  "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scope to the relationship, not to the collection returned by the query.

```
$commenters = $user->commentersOnUserPost()->getBtnDates($startDate, $finishDate)->get();
```

And to resolve your column ambiguity, prepend the table name to the where clause columns. I'm guessing this is `commenters`.

```
public function scopeGetBtnDates($query, $from, $to){
    return $query->whereDate('commenters.created_at', '>=', $from)
        ->whereDate('commenters.created_at', '<=', $to);
}
```